# how to parameterize/correlate in jmeter post requests using (body data - xml / cxml) values?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

- [Post Request Parameterization/Correction Dynamic Value][1]
  HTTPRequest as Post, Path

  1. List item refer screenshot  `In BodyData, i'll provide this xml(soap) data <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?> <Order>  <OrderHeader> <OrderNumber> <BuyerOrderNumber>`QATest1`</BuyerOrderNumber> </OrderNumber>   ... </OrderDetail> </Order>`

  Screenshot - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIbJc.png

  2. Test Result

  After run values should be QATest1, again if i run it should change
  to QATest2, QATest3, how to do get this value dynamically in jmeter
  response and results `

  1. enter code here

  `

Answer (score 0):

Your question is malformed hence it's quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve so I just provide a couple of options:

1. Use [Counter configuration element or __counter() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) as the postfix after the "QATest" like:

   ```
   <BuyerOrderNumber>QATest${__counter(,)}</BuyerOrderNumber>
   ```

   [image]
2. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as the postfix like

   ```
   <BuyerOrderNumber>QATest${__P(number,)}</BuyerOrderNumber>
   ```

   this way you will be able to set the "number" property value using [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) so if you run JMeter as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jnumber=5 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   all the requests will be `<BuyerOrderNumber>QATest5</BuyerOrderNumber>`
3. Any combination of above hints will also work